# How do I ForEach over a One-To-Many Relationship in CoreData using SwiftUI?

Tags: binding, swiftui, observedobject

I am currently working on a SwiftUI App using CoreData. I do currently have 2 entities defined in CoreData.

[image: Recipe Entity]

With Code:

```
extension CoreDataRecipe: Identifiable {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CoreDataRecipe> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CoreDataRecipe>(entityName: "CoreDataRecipe")
    }

    @NSManaged public var recipeName: String
    @NSManaged public var startDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID
    @NSManaged public var recipeSteps: NSOrderedSet

}
```

[image: RecipeStep Entity]

With Code:

```
extension CoreDataRecipeStep: Identifiable {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CoreDataRecipeStep> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CoreDataRecipeStep>(entityName: "CoreDataRecipeStep")
    }

    @NSManaged public var finishDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var isActiveStep: Bool
    @NSManaged public var localStepType: String?
    @NSManaged public var stepDuration: Int32
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?

    var stepType: RecipeStepType {
        set {localStepType = newValue.rawValue}
        get {RecipeStepType(rawValue: localStepType ?? "") ?? .Vorteig}
    }
}
```

I already can circle over the parent one without issues using a ForEach. To do this I am using @ObservedObject. To keep the binding the SwiftUI way.

I do it like this:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: CoreDataRecipe.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var recipes: FetchedResults<CoreDataRecipe>
...
ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
    BreadListItem(recipe: recipe)
}
```

Inside of the BreadListItem, I am using @ObservedObject which works like a charm.

```
@ObservedObject var recipe: CoreDataRecipe
```

What I now want to do, is do the same thing over the steps of my recipe.
My assumption is that I could do this using the same ForEach over the elements in the NSOrderedSet, like so:

```
ForEach(recipe.recipeSteps ?? []) { step in
    RecipeStepEntryField(step: step)
}
```

The problem with this is that I can't loop over these elements because NSOrderedSet does not conform to RandomAccessCollection. Of course I could cast the NSOrderedSet to an array, but that would kill the binding to the object, wouldn't it? I am just not seeing how I could achieve the binding to the set with an @ObservedObject while keeping the CoreData intact.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: I think you can just cast it to an Array and then use the ForEach with the Array. That should work and shouldn't loose the Binding.  Where is transformableRecipeSteps  defined? Can not find it anywhere

Comment: Ah that's right, I forgot to rename this. transformedRecipeSteps is actually recipeSteps. I edited the post now it should be fine. (played around a bit and copied the wrong property in)

Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Tried it. I can get the ForEach to loop over the items without issue with this solution. However this breaks the binding to the @NSManagedObject. So Whenever I add or delete an object to the list of steps, the update does not appear on the screen. Only dismissing the screen and opening it again shows that changes to the actual data occurred.

Comment: Nevermind! I just fixed it! Will post the solution now. :) Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Kein Problem :) Greetings from North Germany :)

Answer (score 4):

With the help of @davidev I was able to figure it out.

The solution was to change the ForEach as follows:

```
ForEach((recipe.recipeSteps?.array as? [CoreDataRecipeStep] ?? [])) { step in
    RecipeStepEntryField(step: (step) as? CoreDataRecipeStep ?? CoreDataRecipeStep(),
    showDetails: true)
}
```

That alone did not work, but since I am working with Xcode 14, I was able to use `@StateObject var recipe: CoreDataRecipe` to keep the reference to the recipe object wich kept me in the loop for updates, but did handle the deletion of the list items of the recipes (not the recipe steps) properly. This caused crashes before, but thanks to the newest addition in SwiftUI this is now possible.

The talk ["Data Essentials in SwiftUI" from the WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/) helped tremendously (luckily watched it a couple of days ago).

Good luck to everyone who tries to do the same thing. CoreData and SwiftUI is really not yet super comfortable to work with but If you're willing to put in a bit of time, it already works. :)

Comment: NSSet doesn't have an .array function. seems like you are using some helper classes you aren't sharing.

Comment: use NSOrderedSet 

Comment: With NSSet use .allObjects

Comment: `NSSet doesn't have an .array function` - just use `map` then: `myCollection.map{$0}`.

Comment: Does this approach only redraw what subviews are needed? I learned recently about how wrong use of ForEach can cause entire UI redraw and am trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I could not compile the code with the combination of ForEach and managed objects with the 1 to many relationship (CoreDataManagedObject -> Tag's). I have added a new computed non optional property tagsArray:

```
extension CoreDataManagedObject {
    public var tagsArray: [Tag] {
        guard let tags else {
           return []
        }
        return Array(_immutableCocoaArray: tags)
    }
}
```

Then the SwiftUI layout compiled without issues with the proxied relationship through the computed property. Also read the documentation related to the Array(_immutableCocoaArray) constructor.